# Mysql - Multiplicate two cols and subtract the difference

Tags: mysql, grouping, multiplication

I have a DB structure in one table like this.
**Id, product_id, in_out, prod_size, prod_amount** and a little example data:

```
1 | 2 | IN | 4 | 2
2 | 2 | UT | 4 | 1
3 | 3 | IN | 3 | 5
```

Now I want to multiplicate **prod_size** with **prod_amount** and get the difference between IN and UT posts grouped by the *product_id*.
I have a beginning of something but it does not count right.

```
SELECT sk1.product_id 'product_id',
(sk2.prod_size*sk2.prod_amount)-(sk1.prod_size*sk1.prod_amount) as availability
FROM tbl sk1
LEFT JOIN tbl sk2 ON sk1.product_id=sk2.product_id
WHERE sk1.in_out='UT' AND sk2.in_out = 'IN'
GROUP BY sk1.product_id
```

So the expected result in this table should be:

```
2 | 4
3 | 15
```

Comment: When I see a group by I expect to see aggregate functions. such as sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to join with itself.

> ```
> select   product_id,
>          sum((prod_size * prod_amount) * if(in_out = 'IN', 1, -1)) total
> from     tbl
> group by product_id
> ```
>
> ```
> product_id | total
> ---------: | ----:
>          2 |     4
>          3 |    15
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=28fa4ccef3ac8f1d36431789bb7df0ab)*